# Canadian income tax & charitable donations: How much is income tax reduced by donations?

Tags: canada, charity, income-tax, tax-deduction, tax-credit

In Canada, how much is income tax reduced by charitable donations?

When filing, are there any special requirements to qualify for the deduction or credit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you file using federal schedule 1 and the corresponding provincial form.

Federally, the credit is a dollar for dollar reduction of the tax payable (it is a non-refundable tax credit). For federal tax, the credit is 15% of the first $200 of donation and 29% on all amounts over $200.
Be aware that the maximum you can claim is limited to 75% of your net income (the excess can be carried forward 5 years).

See the article at http://blog.taxresource.ca/charitable-donation-tax-credit/